# Access properties of old builds in a Workflow job

Tags: jenkins, properties, build, jenkins-workflow

Is it possible to access the last failed build and the last successful build informations within a Workflow Job?

The information I need is the start time of those builds.

Answer (score 0):

This was reposted and some options made available in [JENKINS-29563](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29563). In particular I suggest reading the *Snippet Generator* documentation for `currentBuild`.